# API Integration in photoshop cc 2017 using node js

Tags: node.js, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have written a photoshop script. But instead of placing the file in the script folder, I want to run it from api. I'm not sure if its applicable to do that in photoshop. Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks,

Comment: You already show up in google! https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2385523

Comment: I posted that in adobe forum as well just to get some more help.